# Rails - Checkbox does not change value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using simple_form with a checkbox. I am trying to show a part of the form if my checkbox is checked.

My html.erb looks like that :

```
<div class="form-input">
  <h6>Informations de contact</h6>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 form-inline">
        <p>
            <%= f.check_box :estimation_faite, :id => "estimationCheckbox" %>
        </p>
      <div id="dateEstimation" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <p>
          Date
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Valider", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

And the associated JS is :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('estimationCheckbox').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('dateEstimation')
    if (this.checked) {
      input.style.visibility = 'visible';
      input.disabled = false;
    } else {
      input.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      input.disabled = true;
    }
 });
});
```

Could you please help me if you have a hint.

Thanks

Comment: Your code runs fine with a quick test I did. Can you post the HTML generated not your actual HTML code. It could be that the issue is there.

Comment: Have you got any error log in your browser debugger?

Comment: <div class="col-6 form-inline">
  <p data-children-count="1">
      <input name="client[estimation_faite]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="estimationCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="client[estimation_faite]">
  </p>
  <div id="dateEstimation" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <p>
      Date
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Thks guys for your answer. Above the html generated

Comment: Regards with the browser debugger : it does not seem to detect the event.

Comment: Now I got this in the browser console :

'slider.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (slider.js:34)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 73c425e7a0ee856be26e:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (application.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 73c425e7a0ee856be26e:19)
    at bootstrap 73c425e7a0ee856be26e:62
    at bootstrap 73c425e7a0ee856be26e:62'